# Localization of Bernstein center

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ct.category-theory, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $C$ be a $k$-linear category ($k$ an algebraically closed field) and $Z$ its Bernstein center (the ring of endomorphisms of the identity functor of $C$).

Are there natural assumptions that guarantee that, for every character $\chi : Z \rightarrow k$, the full subcategory $C_{\chi} \subset C$ consisting of objects with ``central character $\chi$'' is non-empty?

I'm most interested in categories of [adjective] representations of infinite groups, or [adjective] modules over non-commutative rings.